# How do you perform a segue from a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my `UITableviewController` I have a `custom cell` with `UITableViewCell subClass`. This `custom cell` contains `UITextField`, I want to perform a segue when `Return key` of keyboard is pressed, inside this `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField`.

How I can create segue in storyboard in this situation? How I can perform segue inside uitableViewCell?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a protocol method in your custom cell and add delegate property.
2. Set your UITableViewController, which contains UITableView with custom cell, as a delegate - do it in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.

   ```
   cell.delegate = self;
   ```
3. Call your protocol method in custom cell inside textFieldShouldReturn: method.

   ```
   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
       [self.delegate yourMethod];
       return YES;
   }
   ```
4. In implementation of your protocol method in your UITableViewController place code to perform a segue.

   ```
   - (void)yourMethod {
       // segue code
   }
   ```

Comment: If I have 15 different custom cell with 15 subclasses of uitableviewcell then I am suppose to create 15 delegates?

Comment: If your protocol methods would be the same, you could make one class with implemented protocol code and then make 15 different subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Create a segue normally in the storyboard, put a name on this segue (for this example, I'm using @"segue name") and  inside textFieldShouldReturn: call this method:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueName" sender:self];
```

Comment: Please try your self how you can create a segue from UITableViewCell subclass.?

Comment: Did you set the class of your custom cell on your storyboard? Other point: this segue don't need necessarily "come" from your custom cell. I would recommend it to "come" from your uiview

Comment: Yes I did set the class in storyboard but I have UITextField inside custom cell, and inside textFieldShouldReturn:  want to perform a segue. How I a suppose to do that?